# Translating C numerical operators to Java Boolean operators

Tags: java, c, logical-operators, boolean-expression

I have the following C code. I want to write a Java version of the C condition but I don't know what boolean operators the C numerical operators represent in the if statement.

The C code is:

```
if ( (n >= 1) * (n < 10) + (n == 0) )
{
     printf("A\n");
}
else
{
     printf("B\n");
    }

    return 0;
```

What boolean operators do * and + translate to?

Comment: I have to ask: is that a quiz or did someone actually put something like that in production code?

Comment: Each comparison results in 0 or 1. If you put these numbers in your expression, you can compare the behaviour of */+ with logical AND/OR operations.

Comment: C relational and logical expressions evaluate to 1 when the operator's condition is satisfied and 0 when it isn't.

Comment: If this is some sort of quiz question, the correct answer is "No answer is possible."  The type of `n` has not been specified so it's not possible to say whether or not the C code can even be translated into Java.  What if `n` is a pointer, for example?  Pointers don't even exist in Java.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca yes it's part of a quiz question but i'm not asking for the solution to the question, it's just part of the process so I can obtain the solution myself.

Comment: @AndrewHenle my question was literally just about creating the java version of this c conditional statement. n is the number inputted into the command line, nothing to do with pointers.

Comment: @curiouscyberkid That is not mentioned in your question.  Your question does not specify what `n` is at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can figure this out by looking at their truth tables.
Keep in mind that in C, `0` is `false`, and any other value (including `1`) is `true`.

```
 *  | 0 | 1      +  | 0 | 1
    |   |           |   |
 ---+---+--      ---+---+--
 0  | 0 | 0      0  | 0 | 1
 ---+---+--      ---+---+--
 1  | 0 | 1      1  | 1 | 2
```

In case this is a homework question, I will leave the rest to you.
If you need more hints, Google for "boolean operation truth table".

Comment: Everything this answer says is correct, but it is not responsive to the question.  In particular "any other value [...] is true" is not helpful for the OP's purposes.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I added that statement to make it clear that `1 + 1 = 2` is still true. If you can think of a better way to phrase that, feel free to edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

just replace * with && (AND) and + with || (OR).